# curl: give downloaded file a dynamic name with hapijs

Tags: curl, hapi.js

i have a hapi js server which makes it possible to download a file.

```
exports.register = function(server, options, next){
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/backup_balancer.zip',
        config: {
            auth: false,
            handler: function(request, reply) {
                let p = request.payload;

                let filename = 'testfilename';

                return reply.file(filePath, {
                    filename: filename
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

if i curl that route like that

```
curl -O http://localhost:8102/backup_balancer.zip
```

curl then saves a file named backup_balancer.zip.

now i like to name my route simply download and use it like that:

```
curl -O http://localhost:8102/download
```

how can i say curl and later the browser to name the file like the filename i return in:

```
return reply.file(filePath, {
    filename: filename
});
```

thank you in advance.

## UPDATE 1

i tried the following with no success. the file is called after the last part of the route. anyone with any further hints?
i am using hapi 13.4.0

```
return reply.file(filePath).header('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testfile.zip;');
```

Comment: You want to send the `Content-Disposition` header. E.g. `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFileName.ext` Don't know how to do that in your server though

Comment: thx. can you give me a hint, how to get this done? i tried ```return reply.file(filePath, {filename: filename}).header('Content-Type', 'application/zip').header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);``` but it is saving a file called like the last part of the routename

Comment: I don't know your server platform at all I'm afraid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to specify mode along with filename for this to work; but I believe the problem is with the behavior you're expecting from curl. See the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html): "The remote file name to use for saving is extracted from the given URL, nothing else." The hapijs code (or inert plugin code) will set content-disposition headers if you give it both filename and mode options, but curl won't pay any attention to those headers. curl gives you an option to specify filename to save on download, and calls it a day.